# How can I show my data in text from firebase database Realtime my code and my XML is in

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I make this project and I can't show my data and search for the serial number in firebase need any help to know where is the problem.
I try and try and watch all firebase tutorials and I can't find the answer.

I am saving data as follows in the Firebase:

[image: My firebase Database]

This is java code:

```
public class Search_For_lost extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView search_input;
    Button search_btn;
    TextView result;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Query query;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_search__for_lost);

        search_input=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search_input);
        result=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.Result_list_view);
        search_btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search_button);
        reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Database").child("Users");
        search_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Database").child("Users");
                Query query=reff.child("Database").orderByChild("Users").equalTo("serial");
                query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                        if (snapshot.exists()){
                            String username=snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString();
                            String serial=snapshot.child("serial").getValue().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),username+ ""+serial, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(Search_For_lost.this, "Serial is not avaliable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
```

This is my Xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".Search_For_lost">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/search_input"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/input_design"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:hint="Search for Serial Number.."
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:padding="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
            android:gravity="center" />
            
        <Button
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/buttons"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Search.."
                android:textSize="25sp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/search_input"
                android:layout_marginTop="70dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Result_list_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_height="350dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/search_button"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>
    
    </RelativeLayout>
```

I can't solve this and every time I run it be it's not Available toast.

Comment: why have you referenced "Database" and "Users" multiple time in search_btn on click method

Comment: Cuz i make it seach for serial number ... if u see any problem tell me

Comment: Stack Overflow is a notoriously inefficient interactive debugger. If you run this code in a debugger, and set breakpoints on every line, which is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: Have you solved the issue? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Answer (score 0):

You have a mistake in the Query.
Instead of this

```
reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Database").child("Users");
Query query=reff.child("Database").orderByChild("Users").equalTo("serial");
```

use this

```
reff= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Database").child("Users");
Query query=reff.orderByChild("serial").equalTo("(here put the serial that you are searching about)");
```

Its pointless to use query and dont know any of the data of the node

Comment: i make methods for search make String and i use query .orderbychild("here the child").startat().endat()

Comment: ok. now when your query is good get the data you need. Just mark my answer as correct.